# Checkbox loses state after dragging row

Tags: jquery, datatables

If I check a checkbox in my DataTables row, via AJAX I update the database and change the flag for that checkbox.  If I then drag that row to a new location, the checkbox goes back to its unchecked state like when the page first loaded.  How do I get the row to keep the state of my checkbox?

Comment: after changing the flag , the data on page is reloaded or you just changed the check box to selected. i think the data is still the old one with unchecked

Comment: No reload.  The screen/DOM show the checked value.  Is there a way to refresh the DataTable without having to reload the entire page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13820587/refreshing-datatable-data-without-reloading-the-whole-page        --------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14091702/reload-datatable-without-reloading-page

Comment: No good.  The checkbox never changes.  The database gets updated but the checkbox keeps showing checked or unchecked no matter how many times you click on it.